# UDP Broadcast doesn't work, What is the problem?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am running a code that supposed to send "Hey" in broadcast, the thing is that it doesn't work and I don't know why. Here is the code:

```
import socket  

def main():
    searcher_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    searcher_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    searcher_socket.sendto("Hey", ("255.255.255.255", 9010))
    response, address = searcher_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    print response

main()
```

I sniffed in Wireshark to check if something comes out of the computer but it seems like nothing is coming out..[image]

Someone can help please? Thanks in advance

**Edit:** I have tested the code on another computer that is connected to the network by cable and not on wifi and it worked. These two computers are sharing the same network. What can be the reason for the code to work on one computer and to fail on the another?

**Second Edit - Solution**: I found the solution. Because the computer is connected via wifi, in order to broadcast you need to bind first the socket with your ip address.

```
import socket  

def main():
    searcher_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    searcher_socket.bind(("192.168.1.11", 40400)) # 192.168.1.11 is my computer ip address
    searcher_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    searcher_socket.sendto("Hey", ("255.255.255.255", 9010))
    response, address = searcher_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    print response

main()
```

Comment: It is *one* of your computer's IP addresses. You need to bind to the address you want to send broadcasts out on, if it isn't the default route.

Comment: Did you fix your problem? I'm having a similar issue

Answer (score 2):

In the code you have posted, function `main` is not called. Add `main()` call

Comment: There is a main() call but I didn't copy it  to here. Sorry for that. Do you see something else that can cause the problem?